# Homebrew: Can't install with options through brew (macOS Mojave)

Tags: macos, terminal, homebrew, sphinx, macos-mojave

I need to install sphinx via homebrew with flags, but there is error

### $ brew install sphinx --mysql --pgsql

```
    Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
    Ignoring byebug-10.0.2 because its extensions are not built.  Try: gem pristine byebug --version 10.0.2
    Usage: brew install [options] formula

    Install formula.

    formula is usually the name of the formula to install, but it can be specified
    in several different ways.

    Unless HOMEBREW_NO_INSTALL_CLEANUP is set, brew cleanup will be run for the
    installed formulae or, every 30 days, for all formulae.
--------------------------------------
    Error: invalid option: --mysql
```

**$ brew -v**

```
Homebrew 2.1.6
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision bacd7; last commit 2019-06-25)
Homebrew/homebrew-cask (git revision 48e24; last commit 2019-06-25)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try manticore (the sphinx fork). We added recently a tap, just `brew tap manticoresoftware/tap && brew install manticoresearch`. Formula compiles with support for all connectors (mysql,postgres,odbc).

Comment: Is it working with sphinx.config files? I need to use thinkingsphinx gem for rails. Is it supported?

Comment: Yes, but check https://docs.manticoresearch.com/latest/html/getting-started/migrate_from_manticore2.html, you might need to make some adjustments due to improvements. Also index storage was upgraded, you'll need to reindex or convert indexes. ThinkingSphinx supports Manticore from some time.

Comment: ==> cmake .. -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE=-DNDEBUG -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local/Cellar/manticoresearch/3.0.3 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE
==> make install
Last 15 lines from /Users/admin/Library/Logs/Homebrew/manticoresearch/02.make: ............... Error: A newer Command Line Tools release is available.

Comment: do you have command line tools installed? ( `xcode-select --install`)

Comment: Seems to be yes. `xcode-select --install` --> 
`xcode-select: error: command line tools are already installed, use "Software Update" to install updates`

Comment: I have reinstalled xcode-select but still got the same error while installing manticore. Here is output https://gist.github.com/unavailabl3/fe69c1257f176f31022c620a4797f149

Comment: seems something different, try installing `brew install icu4c` and do a `--verbose` install of manticore

Comment: Here is output https://gist.github.com/unavailabl3/d631bbe8ab2db95942007b4e1c804c9f

Comment: I see ` fatal error: 'mysql.h' file not found`  and `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql@5.7/5.7.26/include/mysql` (normally it should be  `/usr/local/Cellar/mysql-connector-c/xxx/include` but mysql should also have the header files -  but looks like they are not - maybe try a reinstall of the mysql package)

Answer (score 0):

`--option` support from `hombrew-core` formulae has been removed since Homebrew 2.0.0. Just the formulae repo `homebrew-core`, but not the `brew` command drops the support for `--option`, which means you can still define and use `--option` in your custom formula.

[Release Note of Homebrew 2.0.0](https://brew.sh/2019/02/02/homebrew-2.0.0/)

> Homebrew does not have any formulae with options in `Homebrew/homebrew-core`. Options will still be supported and encouraged by third-party taps. This change allows us to better focus on delivering binary packages rather than options. Formulae with options had to be built from source, could not be tested on our CI system and provided a disproportionate support burden on our volunteer maintainers.

If you wanna additional dependencies in a package, you have to modify the formula and build it by yourself.